# Can we use Robot class to get JFrame of already Open App?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, automated-tests, awtrobot

Is there a way to get a `JFrame` of an application which is already Open using the Robot class? I do not have access to the Class file to run the Swing App.

I plan to use the AssertJ library and TestNG to automate a Swing Based app which can be accessed over Citrix.